# MikroORM: How to set foreign key by raw id?

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

In MikroORM, how can you set a foreign key by its raw numeric value? For example, in Django ORM you can do this:

```py
b = new Book()
b.author = someAuthorWithId1
```

and this, with raw id

```py
b = new Book()
b.author_id = 1
```

How can use raw id in MikroORM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 2024 update

Nowadays (v6+) there is also the `rel` and `ref` helpers that can create unmanaged entity reference:

```
const b = new Book();
// or ref() if the relation uses Reference wrapper
b.author = rel(Author, 1);
```

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-constructors#pojo-vs-entity-instance-in-constructor

---

There are several ways:

1. using references:

```
const b = new Book();
b.author = em.getReference(Author, 1);
```

2. using `assign` helper:

```
const b = new Book();
em.assign(b, { author: 1 });
```

3. using `create` helper:

```
const b = em.create(Book, { author: 1 });
```